# Search Datasheet Column

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a datasheet on a form with a qdf as recordsource.

I'd like to provide ability to search a specific column in the datasheet for the first/next occurrence (row) of the wildcarded string from a textbox on the same form (e.g., Jump to NEXT RECORD with MfgID like *123*).

I'm not really looking for a FILTER, as I need to see the matching record(s) in context of surrounding records.

Any suggestions how to begin?

Comment: See [Recordset.FindFirst Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221033(v=office.12).aspx) or [FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243105(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Just curious, Jean-Francoise, why the down vote?  Is that yours?

Seems a fair enough question, the posted comment does point me in the right direction (thanks HansUp), I upvoted the response.  Once I implement, I will provide my ultimate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks HansUp for the pointer.  Here is what I implemented:

```
1.  Sets focus to the desired column
2.  Supports multiple btn clicks, to keep looking for the NEXT occurence
3.  When no_match or end of list, returns to first record, clears txtSearch

--------------

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim rs As Object

On error goto err_handler

  Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form![MFGID].SetFocus
  Set rs = Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.RecordsetClone
  rs.FindNext "[MfgID] like '*" & Me![txtSearch] & "*'"

  If Not Trim(Me![txtSearch]) = "" Then
      Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
  Else
      MsgBox "Please enter search criteria.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
      Me![txtSearch].SetFocus
      Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not rs.NoMatch Then
      Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
  Else
      MsgBox "Match not found for: " & Me![txtSearch] & "", , "Error"
      rs.MoveFirst
      Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
      Me![txtSearch] = ""
  End If

err_exit:

  Exit Sub

err_handler:

  If Err.Number = 2455 Then GoTo err_exit
  MsgBox Err.Number

exit sub
```